# Why is a USB bulk transfer with Perl's Device::USB cut off?

Tags: linux, perl, usb

I ran this Perl code running on Linux:

```
my $command = "\x{11}\x{22}\x{33}\x{44}\x{55}\x{66}\x{77}\x{88}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}\x{00}"; # total of 20 bytes to transmit
my $bytesWritten = $device->bulk_write(0x01, $command, 1000);
```

Using Wireshark, I found the actual application data transmitted to be

```
0000    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0010    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    11 22 33 44
```

Printing `$bytesWritten` reveals that 20 bytes were transferred, but this is different from what was captured by Wireshark.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can someone show me the right way to form a bulk_transfer URB? Should the byte variable contain just the command/data that I would like to send, or is there anything else I need to put in there?

Comment: @daxim, thanks for showing me how to make my post more readable :)

Comment: Does the information at http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB shed any light? i.e., are you using kernel >= 2.6.21 and libpcap >= 1.1.0?

Comment: What does strace of perl show?  How many were requested to be pushed via a system call and how many did the system call say were sent?

Comment: what version of libusb are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Perl program is working properly.

I've seen wireshark truncate the USB packets (one other reference:
http://www.mail-archive.com/tcpdump-workers@lists.tcpdump.org/msg04042.html).

I had to use "usbmon" application to get the full capture:
http://people.redhat.com/zaitcev/linux/